# How to get the ip address of my computer not the virtual box adapters

Tags: java, python, windows, sockets, networking

In Java I'm trying to get the local machines ip address

```
String address = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
```

and in python I have

```
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

both of these do not return the ip address that I'm looking for. Now I have VirtualBox installed with a couple virtual machines but they aren't on while I run the above 2 lines. Looking at my network connections it shows that I've got a lan adapter for VirtualBox and when I look at the ip that the above code returns and look at the ip for the virtualbox adapter they're the same. Is there any way for me to get my computers local IPv4 Address instead of the other virtual adapter ip's without disabling them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A machine can have many IP addresses. The following will enumerate all adapters and show the address(es) for each adapter:

```
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> i = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while(i.hasMoreElements())
    {
        NetworkInterface n = i.nextElement();
        System.out.println(n.getName());
        Enumeration<InetAddress> ea = n.getInetAddresses();
        while(ea.hasMoreElements())
        {
            InetAddress a = ea.nextElement();
            System.out.println("   "+a.toString());
        }
    }
```

It's up to you to figure out which adapter(s) and address(es) you're interested in.